# Remover dicionário de dados da session com ajax no Django

Tags: javascript, ajax, python, django

Tenho um array com um dicionário de dados em minha session e gostaria de remover de acordo com a linha que o usuário for clicar em uma tabela onde esses valores são exibidos.

Minha view:

```
def deletar_servico_ou_item_selecionado(request):

    if request.is_ajax:
        linhaClicada = request.POST.get('item')
        lista = request.session['ord-serv']
        del lista[linhaClicada - 1]
        request.session['ord-serv'] = lista

    return HttpResponse("/")
```

Meu JS:

```
var linhaClicada = $(this).parent().index();
$.ajax({
    url: "/atendimento/deletar-servico-ou-item-selecionado/",
    type: "POST",
    data: {item: linhaClicada},
    success: function(response) {
        console.log("Success");
    },
    error: function(response) {
        console.log("Error");
    }
});
```

Parece que o meu valor na chega até Django e também não sei se devo usar o `type: "DELETE"` nesse caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para remover o item da sua lista partir do índice, você pode utilizar o list.pop, por exemplo:

```
lista = [{"0":"0"},{"1":"1"},{"2":"2"},{"3":"3"},{"4":"4"},{"5":"5"}]
lista.pop(1)
# {'1': '1'}
lista
# [{'0': '0'}, {'2': '2'}, {'3': '3'}, {'4': '4'},{"5":"5"}]
```

Caso não seja necessário csrf_token na sua requisição, você pode incluir no início da sua função o `@csrf_exempt`, e importá-lo `from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt`. Caso sim, você deve passar junto com os dados que está dando post. data : {csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'}

Comment: Obrigado por sua resposta, mas o meu problema é `linhaClicada` não chega até o AJAX.

Comment: Coloca um dataType: "json", em baixo do seu data: {item: linhaClicada}. Verifica também se ao chamar o ajax, ainda no script, existe algum valor para linhaClicada

Comment: Você deve observar também o seu console log para ver se existe algum erro no script e se a view está sendo chamada corretamente. Você pode debugar o que está chegando no seu post com o pdb. import pdb; pdb.set_trace() https://mike.tig.as/blog/2010/09/14/pdb/

Comment: E coloca o seu dicionário entre aspas. data: {"item": linhaClicada}, :)

Comment: Está aparecendo a seguinte mensagem: `list indices must be integers, not NoneType`, mas minha linhaClicada tem um valor.

Comment: Na sua view, tenta pegar os dados com: data = request.POST['data']. Você tem que ver o que está chegando na sua view e como está chegando. Você deve estar enviando a informação para a view mas não está pegando da maneira correta.

Comment: Provavelmente é isso, agora está apresentando o seguinte erro: `MultiValueDictKeyError at /atendimento/deletar-servico-ou-item-selecionado/
"'item'"`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30873/discussion-between-puam-dias-and-rodrigo-boniatti).